# Why "AWS Account" tab is missing from https://www.awseducate.com/ in my dashboard?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Recently I got access to AWS Educate account.
After getting confirmation I want to use Console in AWS but "AWS Account" is missing from my dashboard.
In the mail it's clearly mentioned that to access  AWS Console and resources click on AWS account at top right corner.

[image]

But I my dashboard I am not getting this tab.

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for Programming Q&A. You should contact AWS Educate support for assistance: [AWS Educate | Contact Us](https://aws.amazon.com/education/awseducate/contact-us/)

Comment: I had the same issue. I wrote my teacher an E-Mail. He added me. After this the "AWS account" tab did appear.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue!
This is the response of the Aws support :

If a Students applies to the Educate program via an invite sent to them by their Educators whom are also members of the Educate program they will receive access to an Educate Starter Account(ESA)

Students who sign up without a classroom invite would not include the Educate Starter Account, it does however include access to Educate Pathways, Badges and additional training materials.